# GWT Grid editing Tab Order

Tags: gwt, gxt

I use GXT (sencha version 3.0.1)

I have grid like this:

[image]

When I select second Column and try to move next Column use Tab Key to move and its works fine,
but when I select any value from combo and after try to move next Column its go somewhere else (outside of grid).

what to do? I need to focus (edit next column) on Tab key. 
tried this but not works:

```
combo2.addSelectionHandler( new SelectionHandler<Street>() {
    @Override
    public void onSelection( SelectionEvent<Street> event ) { 
        grid.getSelectionModel().selectNext( false );
    }
} );
```

What to do?

Comment: Could it be this bug: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6911

Comment: I don't use Microsoft IE (I use chrome)

Comment: The ComboBox uses a list view to display the contents of the list store. My guess is that when you hit the drop-down, you are giving focus to the ListView. One solution may be to add a `combo2.focus()` call inside that listener. This would be an attempt to put the focus back on the combo2 so you can get back to the correct tab orders.

Comment: already tried it but not works (p.s. ComboBoxCell has no focus function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
combo2.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Street>() {

            @Override
            public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Street> event) { 
                streetCombo.resetFocus(null, grid.getView().getCell(0, 2), null);
            }
        });
```

I done this and its works now, when you choose value it jump to next combobox (0,2 mean 0 row and 2 column )